# Using windows 10 for malware analysis

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows, malware

I want to ask can I use windows 10 for malware analysis, I'm asking this because I see many reversers and analysts using windows 7 for this purpose. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: In all likelihood the reason Windows 7 is used has to do with certain security measures of the OS which can be more easily circumvented on Windows 7. But that only applies to dynamic analysis. Static analysis - as referenced in the answer - is even possible on Linux with or without Wine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows 10 can be used for malware analysis.  All the modern RE tools, such as IDA Pro, Ghidra, Binary Ninja, etc. run on it.